# Unity UI: Pinch to zoom on image.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been searching and testing on how to implement Zoom in/out on a UI image, and everything i found is Zoom in/out on a Sprite render which works good actually. I'm trying to build it to work on a mobile and UI image instead of the sprite render. Sprite render zoom can be found [here](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/pinch-zoom-panning-unity).

Can anyone Help on how to achieve this?

What i have tried so far:
So Im thinking about this and i'm getting the idea of actually using a scrollrect and mask the UI image, and when i want to zoom in just scale it bigger however this will just make it scale then movable . what i want for example if user pinches on top corner, i want image to zoom in top corner and not in the middle then scroll to the top corner. Therefore this didn't work for me or i didn't know how to procced from there.

Other thing im thinking is to get the 2 touches and getting the difference between the touches and then scale?

Anyone who did this and can share their knowledge?

Thanks